# Multiple table joining query in Oracle SQL plus 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables.

1. table `SCHOOL`: schoolcode(PK), year, schoolname.
2. table `ENROLMENT`: schoolcode, year, classname, enrol
3. table `CLASS`: schoolcode, year, classid, rooms

Now, I want to find the list of schools with enrollment in classname - 1 to 4 and number of classrooms used by class 1-4.

I used the following query:

```
select 
    m.schoolcode, m.schoolname, sum(e.c1+e.c2+e.c3+e.c4), sum(c.rooms) 
from 
    dise2k_enrolment09 e, dise2k_master m, dise2k_clsbycondition 
where 
    m.schoolcode = e.schoolcode 
    and m.schoolcode = c.schoolcode 
    and e.year = '2011-12' and m.year = '2011-12' and c.year = '2011-12' 
    and classid in (1,2,3,4) 
    and e.classname in (1,2,3,4) 
group by 
    m.schoolcode, m.schoolname
```

but the result showing is not correct. Enrollment is showing much higher than actual, same in case of classrooms.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select m.schoolcode, m.schoolname, sum(e.c1+e.c2+e.c3+e.c4), sum(c.rooms) 
from dise2k_enrolment09 e, dise2k_master m ,dise2k_clsbycondition c
where m.schoolcode=e.schoolcode and m.schoolcode=c.schoolcode and e.year='2011-12' and m.year='2011-12' and c.year='2011-12' 
and c.classid in(1,2,3,4) 
and e.classname = c.classid
group by m.schoolcode, m.schoolname
```

The way you have it: `and e.classname in(1,2,3,4)` is like having an `OR` operator in your where clause.

```
(c.classid=1 or c.classid=2 or c.classid=3 or c.classid=4) 
and 
(e.classname=1 or e.classname=2 or e.classname=3 or e.classname=4)
```

So, c.classid can be "1" and e.classname can be "2" which is wrong

**UPDATE**  I still think the problem is that you don't connect the `c.classid` with `e.classname`

Try it like this:

```
select m.schoolcode, m.schoolname, sum(e.c1+e.c2+e.c3+e.c4), sum(c.rooms) 
from dise2k_enrolment09 e, dise2k_master m ,dise2k_clsbycondition c
where m.schoolcode=e.schoolcode and m.schoolcode=c.schoolcode and e.year='2011-12' and m.year='2011-12' and c.year='2011-12' 
and c.classid in(1,2,3,4) 
and c.classid = decode(e.classname,1,7,2,7,3,8,4,8,5,9,6,9,7,10,8,10)
group by m.schoolcode, m.schoolname
```

Comment: No. Classname and classid are not the same thing. its an example. sorry, its my mistake, that i couldnt explain my problemto you very well. actually, classname has values 1 to 8, but classid has values 7,8,9,10 (as 7 for class 1,2 ; 8 for class 3,4; 9 for class 5,6; and 10 for class 7,8). I wrote, classid in(7,8). Now can you help me to find the answer. because both the above answers didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 select m.schoolcode, m.schoolname, sum(e.c1+e.c2+e.c3+e.c4), sum(c.rooms) 
from dise2k_enrolment09 e join dise2k_master m
on  m.schoolcode=e.schoolcode 
join dise2k_clsbycondition c
on m.schoolcode=c.schoolcode
where  e.year='2011-12' and m.year='2011-12' and c.year='2011-12' 
and classid in(1,2,3,4) 
and e.classname in(1,2,3,4) 
group by m.schoolcode, m.schoolname
```

Comment: No. Classname and classid are not the same thing. its an example. sorry, its my mistake, that i couldnt explain my problemto you very well. actually, classname has values 1 to 8, but classid has values 7,8,9,10 (as 7 for class 1,2 ; 8 for class 3,4; 9 for class 5,6; and 10 for class 7,8). now can you help me to find the answer. because both the above answers didnt work.

Comment: No. Classname and classid are not the same thing. its an example. sorry, its my mistake, that i couldnt explain my problemto you very well. actually, classname has values 1 to 8, but classid has values 7,8,9,10 (as 7 for class 1,2 ; 8 for class 3,4; 9 for class 5,6; and 10 for class 7,8). I wrote, classid in(7,8). Now can you help me to find the answer. because both the above answers didnt work.